# Function has too many arguments specified in Sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server

In the below code i have a function and a query the function will return batchrelease quantity.I have include the function in the select sqlquery it throws a error"Procedure or function dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantity has too many arguments specified.".Please help me to overcome this issue.

```
SELECT   p.ProductID,
   p.ProductName,
   ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL( CurrentStock,0.00) 
    FROM   Productstatus PS
    WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
           AND PS.LocationID = 1
           AND PS.StatusDateTime= '2014-08-27'
           and PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockQuantity,
          ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL( (CurrentStock*PS.UnitPrice),0.00) 
    FROM   Productstatus PS
    WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
           AND PS.LocationID = 1
           AND PS.StatusDateTime= '2014-08-27'
           and PS.productid=p.productid),0) OpeningStockValue,
           ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL( CurrentStock,0.00) 
    FROM   Productstatus PS
    WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
           AND PS.LocationID = 1
           AND PS.StatusDateTime= '2014-08-27'
           and PS.productid=p.productid),0) ClosingStockQuantity,
          ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL( (CurrentStock*PS.UnitPrice),0.00) 
    FROM   Productstatus PS
    WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
           AND PS.LocationID = 1
           AND PS.StatusDateTime= '2014-08-27'
           and PS.productid=p.productid),0) ClosingStockValue,
           (SELECT dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantity(1,2, '2014-01-27 00:00:00', '2014-11-27 23:59:59')  AS BatchReleaseQuantity
        FROM   Productstatus PS   
        WHERE    
                PS.LocationID = 1 
              and PS.productid=p.productid AND PS.StatusDateTime > = '2014-01-27 00:00:00' AND PS.StatusDateTime <= '2014-10-27 23:59:59' ) 

    --        ISNULL((SELECT ISNULL( (dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantity(1,2, '2014-01-27 00:00:00', '2014-11-27 23:59:59')),0.00) 
    --FROM   Productstatus PS
    --WHERE  PS.ProductID =p.ProductID
    --       AND PS.LocationID = 1
    --       AND PS.StatusDateTime= '2014-08-27'
    --       and PS.productid=p.productid),0) Batchout

           FROM   Product P
   --- SELECT dbo.GetBatchReleaseQuantity(@i_LocationID,P.ProductID,@i_Date,@i_Date) From Product P      




LEFT OUTER JOIN LocationProductMap LMP ON LMP.ProductID=P.ProductID
WHERE LMP.ProductInFlow=1
```

Function

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
()  
RETURNS int  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  

 DECLARE @i_LocationID VARCHAR(50)  
 DECLARE @i_ProductID INT  
 DECLARE @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50)  
 DECLARE @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50)  


  RETURN (SElECT SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity) AS BatchReleaseQuantity From  BatchReleaseDetails BRD
   LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
    Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND LocationID=@i_LocationID AND BRD.CreatedOn>=@i_StartDate AND BRD.CreatedOn<=@i_EndDate)
```

Comment: Looks to me like the variable decs in the function are in the wrong place.

Answer (score 4):

Your function doesn't have any parameters, you need to put them in the `()`, for example:

```
CREATE FUNCTION Add
(
    @P1 INT,
    @P2 INT
)
RETURNS INT
AS
BEGIN
    RETUTN @P1 + @P2
END
```

So change yours to something like this by moving the variables to be parameters instead:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetBatchReleaseQuantity]   
(
    @i_LocationID VARCHAR(50),
    @i_ProductID INT,
    @i_StartDate VARCHAR(50),  
    @i_EndDate VARCHAR(50)  
)  
RETURNS int  
 --WITH ENCRYPTION     
AS  
BEGIN  
  RETURN (SELECT SUM( BatchReleaseQuantity) AS BatchReleaseQuantity From  BatchReleaseDetails BRD
   LEFT OUTER JOIN BatchRelease BR ON BR.BatchReleaseID=BRD.BatchReleaseID
    Where  ProductId=@i_ProductID  AND LocationID=@i_LocationID AND BRD.CreatedOn>=@i_StartDate AND BRD.CreatedOn<=@i_EndDate)
END
```

Also you probably need to think about how you are calling it as you appear to be passing in an `INT` as the first parameter but in the function it's declared as a `VARCHAR(50)`. So it may need to be that your `@i_LocationID` parameter should be an `INT`.

Comment: when i execute the above query it throws subquery return more than one value

Comment: That's a problem with your stored procedure and is another problem completely. Deconstruct the query into parts that work and join them together one by one.